# Making a card having text and image using Row and an inner Column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-card

My card's text part has multiple text widgets that I have to put under `column`. I want to add this whole part under a `row` widget, so that I can add the image part to the right of this column widget.

This is what I've done:

```
class ContactMe extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String route = '/contact_me';
  const ContactMe({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CommonNavBar(height: height),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: contactMe(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data == null)
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  else {
                    var data = snapshot.data as List<String>;
                    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                      if (constraints.maxWidth < 1000) {
                        return Center();
                      } else {
                          return Row(  //this is parent row
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Column( //the column that contains multiple other widgets
                                  children: [
                                    text('Reach Out to me!', 25,
                                        Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight),
                                    Text('anything'),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Image.asset('assets/contact_me/' + data[2], scale: 2), //the image widget
                            ],
                          );
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But instead of a card, the layout looks like this:

[image]

As visible in the picture, the image for some reason is not in line with the column widget. What's the mistake I'm making here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related to different alignments. The default `crossAxisAlignment` for a Row is `CrossAxisAlignment.center`, thus your image and column are located in the vertical middle of the row. The default `mainAxisAlignment` for a Column is `MainAxisAlignment.start`, so the content inside your column is located at its top.

I can see two possible ways to put your content on the same horizontal line:

1. Set `mainAxisAlignment` for the Column to `MainAxisAlignment.center`
2. Set `crossAxisAlignment` for the Row to `CrossAxisAlignment.start`

For the future, you might find this resource helpful when dealing with different layouts: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout

Comment: Hey thanks. It didn't work entirely correctly. But gave me the general idea. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

In continuation to [@OlegBezr's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70254015/10951873) answer, I fixed it by using `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment` for both the widgets.

```
return Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, //takes the row to the top
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, //Used this for spacing between the children
  children: [
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,  //used for aligning the children vertically
      children: [
        text('Reach Out to me!', 25,
          Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight),
        text(
          'DISCUSS A PROJECT OR JUST WANT TO SAY HI? MY INBOX IS OPEN FOR ALL.',
          18,
          Theme.of(context)
            .primaryColorLight
            .withOpacity(0.3)),
       ],
    ),
    Image.asset('assets/contact_me/' + data[2], scale: 2),
  ],
);
```

[image]